# How to put the first occurence of a line in a file into a %hash with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

For example, given this data:

```
ID1 2 3 4 
ID1 2 4 5 
ID2 2 6 8
ID2 4 6 7 
ID3 3 5 6
```

I would like to read a file handle and loop through it taking the first line until the ID does not match the previous ID and then continue till end of file so my output file looks like:

```
ID1 2 3 4 
ID2 2 6 8 
ID3 3 5 6
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -ane '$s{$F[0]}++ or print' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

my %data;
while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    next if exists $data{$split[0]};
    $data{$split[0]} = [$split[1], $split[2], $split[3] ];
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of your code to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or, like @mpapec's solution but as an anonymous hash (`%_`):

```
perl -ane '${$F[0]}++ or print' file.txt
```

At that point I'm really just doing silly code golf though ....

Comment: Actually it's not anon hash, but symbolic reference which manipulates `main::` package variables. https://eval.in/165835

Comment: oopsie.  So the "default hash" `%_` here would be `%main::` ? Is that bad/slow/silly? :-D  I assumed since it was run with -`ane` it would be inside an implicit `{}` somehow. Anyway good to know, thanks.

Comment: `-n` does implicit `while(<>){}`, and `-a` splits line into `@F`.  Check `Symbolic references of scalar variables` part at http://perlmaven.com/symbolic-reference-in-perl